# nginx HttpAuthDigestModule

Tags: nginx

I have to problem to login in secure folder 
nginx conf

```
    auth_digest_user_file /var/www/*******/htpasswd/passwd.digest;  
    location /private {

    auth_digest 'this is not for you';
    }
```

work login but i can access to site ... say 403 error